# Map Projection invented by woman

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography

Is there any map projection of the earth that has been invented by a woman?

Context: I am starting a math outreach program and one of the activities I am proposing involves playing with different maps projections. I also want to give a historical perspective on the different maps projections and the related debates stemming from these.

Comment: Anna van Westerstee Beek is worth researching (1657-1717) was a dutch map publisher (and also had 7 children.) Her work can be found in the Map Division's collection at the U.S. Library of Congress.

Comment: @Mapperz: thank you for your suggestion! Anna Beek seems to have produced only small maps, but there might indeed people at the Library of Congress who could answer my question.

Comment: https://futuremaps.com/blogs/news/the-women-who-shaped-the-world

Answer (score 3):

Dr. Maria E. Fleis

1. Meridian section projections: a new class of the triaxial ellipsoid
   projections. https://doi.org/10.22389/0016-7126-2021-968-2-11-22
2. Conic projections of the triaxial ellipsoid: The projections for
   regional mapping of celestial bodies. https://doi.org/10.3138/cart.52.4.2017-0002
3. Equal-area projections of the triaxial ellipsoid: first time
   derivation and implementation of cylindrical and azimuthal
   projections for small solar system bodies.  https://doi.org/10.1080/00087041.2015.1119471

The projections are mostly for small solar system bodies but they all have terrestrial applicability.

From number 2 above.

*Different distortion classes of the azimuthal and cylindrical projections of the triaxial ellipsoid have been considered in our previous works. These projections make it possible to construct maps of the celestial bodies in planetary scale. However, for regions in the middle latitudes it is advisable to use a conic projection which was not developed until now. In this investigation we describe the development of three conic projections of a triaxial ellipsoid: a conic projection with true scale along meridians, an equal-area conic projection and a quasi-conformal conic projection. In derivation of the projections we use an elliptical cone tangent to a triaxial ellipsoid. The projections are calculated and maps in these projections are created for the first time.*